# Repeated Measures Mixed model Design

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, genetics

I am trying to model gene count data from an RNA seq experiment. In the experiment subjects were selected from 2 predefined groups. 5 Subjects from group A and 10 subjects were selected from B. For each participant, isolated cells were infected with a bacterium and then lysed at 1 and 6 hours. RNA was extracted from the lysates infected and uninfected for both time points and sequenced.

In summary subjects selected from 2 groups with each subject having infected and uninfected samples at 1 and 6 hours.
I am trying to use a mixed model approach to model the gene expression and determine if there is a significant difference in the expression of genes from infected samples between GroupA and GroupB.

The subjects are nested in the group, but crossed with infection and time.

The simplest model I could define given this is by including subjects as a random effect.
In addition to age and sex which are covariates I've considered:

```r
Gene expression ~ Age + Sex + Group*Infection*Time + 
                 (1|Group/Subject)
```

(here to show subject is nested in group)

Alternatively:

```r
Gene expression ~ Age + Sex + Group*Infection*Time + 
                 (1|Subject)
```

I appreciate any feedback or further suggested reading material. I've read many posts and also material by Bolker but am finding it difficult to apply to my example.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use age and sex as covariates? Also, do you have multiple technical replicates per sample?

Comment: Yes, age has an affect on the phenotype, but I could leave out sex. Unfortunately, I do not have technical replicates.

Comment: Great. It seems like the second model is correct, though I'm not sure it makes a difference, given that subjects are nested within groups. It's not clear to me what "infection" is - are there different strains of bacteria or something?

Comment: Thank you so much. No it is infection with one strain of bacterium only. The same samples are paired uninfected and infected at both 1 and 6 hours.

Comment: Ahh, I see. It seems like you have a split-plot design, then. Perhaps this reading will be helpful: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/split-plot-designs-the-transition-to-mixed-models-for-a-dinosaur/.  I wouldn't treat this as a repeated measures experiment, either - if for each combo of subject and infection, you only have two time points, why not just reduce that to the difference between the time points?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look into split-plot designs. Could you please clarify what you mean with 'reduce that to the difference between the time points' or rather how this relates back to the model design.

Comment: Well, I am presuming you don't actually care about effect of time - the value you actually care about is the difference in your measurement between the time points, right? So instead of having two "time point" measurements for each subject and infection, just have a single "difference" value. At that point, you could reduce your test to a ANOVA-style randomization test and not have to use a mixed model at all, which would actually be nice - your experiment lends itself well to a permutation test.